# :after height 100 % with bootstrap empty column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hellu!

I'm using Bootstrap and want to have a column that acts as a divider with the setup looking like this:

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 divider"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    ... content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.divider:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I can't get it be displayed with a 100 % height, though. I've tried experimenting with different displays for the ::after, setting 100 % height on both the .divider and .row, but nothing seems to work.

I'd prefer if this way could be used, instead of having a border, since I'll have more control over it (if it works).

I've seen some other posts here on Stack Overflow, but they either don't use the pseudo-element or they have position: absolute set to the column, which I obviously can't use.

Comment: What is the CSS for the `divider` div? If that doesn't have a height, then the pseudo element can't be 100% of something that isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap grid, then there is a class that will help you to create a divider gap between your columns. For that you have to use `offset` with grids. Here's a example for your code.

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        ... content ...
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        ... content ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Read more at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you need the .divider (column) element to be 100% of the parent (row) height. I had a similar problem and came up with the following findings:

1) If your divider column height appears to be too large, vertically, try setting overflow to 'hidden'

```
.divider { overflow: hidden;}
```

2) If you are not seeing your divider pseudo element at all, try adding top and left/right positioning e.g.

```
.divider:after {/*... other styles... */  top: 0px; right: 0px;}
```